# Mssql Russian text search query not working in Linux server

Tags: linux, sql-server-2005, cakephp

I am using CAKEPHP and Sql Server 2005. In my application i need to search russian text. It is working fine in my local environment(Windows). But In Linux server it is returning empty result.

For Ex.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE columnname LIKE '%Испания%';
```